# How to name a list variable with ending "s"

Tags: python, ruby, naming-conventions

How should one name a list variable with ending `s`:

```
fpss,frame_rates, audios,
```

or

```
fps_records = []
frame_rate_records = []
audio_records = []
```

Comment: Why would you put `record` in the name? It seems to offer no additional clarity, especially since it tells you nothing about the element type.

Comment: @user2357112 I would imagine a "record" is more than a single scalar value .. although I agree that it should not generally be done wholesale and that something like `audioTracks` or `fpsStats` would more informative.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think adding `_records` to the end adds anything of value. Avoid adding length to names that don't add clarity or insight for future reviewers, which will certainly include yourself. Adding meaningless verbiage will only serve to make your code harder to read and therefore harder to maintain.

If you think you're going to look at `fps` later and forget it's a list, use `fps_list`, which directly tells what type it is to any reader.

Please no-one interpret me as suggesting Hungarian notation. But I do do this when I'm starting out with a list, realize order doesn't matter and I need set-like behavior, and then realize I actually needed a mapping in the first place. Using that sort of convention allows me to implement my new structure completely without breaking the old.

For example, see this Python-style pseudo-code:

*Iteration 1*

```
def foo():
    data = []
    get_data_from_source()...
```

*Iteration 2*

```
def foo():
    data_list = []
    data_set = set()
    get_data_from_source()...
```

*Iteration 3*

```
def foo():
    data_set = set()
    data_dict = {}
    get_data_from_source()...
```

*Iteration 4*

```
def foo():
    data = {}
    get_data_from_source()...
    return data
```

Comment: yes, records is kind of meaningless, but I don't know how to name the fps in plural

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Arone, however if required I would go with adding **lst**(like lst_records) with list(same we follow in legacy lang like vb) variables so if you would start typing lst immediately IDE would start suggesting all list.