# Naming convention list when objects ends with "s"

Tags: list, naming-conventions

A normal list can be called like this (this is what I learned at school):

```
List<Object> objects = new List<Object>();
```

But, how does a list has to be called when the object itselfs ends with a "s".

```
List<Octopus> octopuss = new List<Octopus>();
List<Boss> bosss = new List<Boss>();
```

It seems wierd to add another s.
Not many (single) words end with "s". So, this is one of the first time I encountered it. Did anyone found a source where this is explained?

**EDIT**

These words have a plural noun. But what about these:

```
List<Series> series? = new List<Series>();
List<Species> species? = new List<Species>();
```

Comment: Wouldn't it simply be `Bosses` as that is the _plural_ of `Boss`?  Also isn't `Octopi` the plural of `Octopus` (just to make it more difficult).  Alternatively, why not adopt the convention `OctopusList` or `OctopusCollection`, removing the need to worry about this entirely

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to name a list variable with ending "s"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368478/how-to-name-a-list-variable-with-ending-s)

Answer (score 2):

1- variable names should be started with lowerCase
   i.e. List objects = ...

2- for multiple data, you learned to have **basic english plurals**.

object -> objects

disk -> disks

**with one's ending with 's':**

boss -> bosses

octopus -> octopi **OR** octopuses

Refer: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/plural-nouns/

Comment: Thanks for answering.
1) I did copy it from my code. It is a public list.
2) Ahh like that, I just thought it was simply adding a "s".